# How to obtain x values for 2 data sets in a line plot where y == 80?

Tags: r, plot

I have two separate .csv files that I have loaded into R (version 3.1.2), and produced a simple plot with data from both files using the `plot()` function as below:

```
plot(db1[ ,2],db1[ ,5], type = "l", xlab = "area", ylab = "represented", main = "title", frame.plot = FALSE, col = 'blue', pch = 20) 
lines(db2[ ,3], db2[ ,7], col="red", pch = 20, )
abline(h=80,col= 'black',lty=2)
```

This is the plot:

[image: Plot]

What I would like to do is obtain the value of x for each of the two data sets, where y == 80. The values do not exist in the dataset - I would need to interpolate them. An example dataset can be found [on my Google Drive here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B_JZ_N73nsl_UzlYc3dpZ294RUE).

Searching through the literature, I can see that I can use `identify` or `locate` and use the mouse to find the y-values, but I would like a more accurate value than these functions can provide. Is there something I can add to the plot code to obtain specific values for x where y == 80? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since both the x- and y-values come directly from `df`, you can simply subset your data frame.

```
# Blue plot
df[df[, 5] == 80, 2]

# Red plot
df[df[, 7] == 80, 3]
```

For the blue line, this gets the value of the second column of `df`, i.e. `df[, 2]` such that the fifth column, `df[, 5]` is equal to 80. Likewise for the red line.

The syntax for subsetting a data frame by row is as follows:

```
df[<row subsetting>, <column selection>]
```

The row subsetting can be a list of indices to select, or a logical vector that's `TRUE` at the indices we wish to select. In this case we're using the latter. The column selection is simply a list of columns to return, and in this case we're just getting a single column.

Comment: I just want to point out that it's possible that the value 80 is never actually realized. In which case, you might be interested in the closest value to 80 or maybe an approximation of a suitable x value.

Comment: @blakeoft: That's true. I figured if that was a concern of the OP, it would have been addressed in the question. This answer addresses only that which was specifically asked.

Comment: Ah my bad. The values are not actually in the df itself.  I would need to interpolate the value.

Sorry for leaving that crucial bit of information I left out.  I have edited the OP

Comment: Also, thank you @AlexA. for adding the plot image.  Much appreciated.

Comment: @HoboSci: In that case it would be good to provide some example data. Interpolation can be as simple as averaging the two nearest values less than and greater than 80 (pretty decent depending on the sample size), or it can get much more complicated.

Comment: @AlexA. Thanks for your patience.  I have placed an example of one of the datasets and short explainer of what I am after in google drive http://ow.ly/MboYT

Comment: @HoboSci: Would it work to just select the minimum `x` such that `y` is greater than or equal to 80? That would give you an observed value. Otherwise what method of interpolation would you want to use?

Comment: Appologies for not fully responding.  I'm being asked to do this work which is quite beyond my skills (I'm just starting to teach myself R).  I will come back with a solution/response when I have something more firm to bring to the table.  Thank you for your assistance so far, I am very grateful for it.